# What am I doing wrong? Java Drawing an Image to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

This is for an assignment, so I'd rather not ask for help, but I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. The code will eventually create a window, with an image as the background, and then using information in a text file, place other images at specific points, and the user can zoom in.

At the moment I'm just trying to get an image displayed onto a JPanel inside a JFrame, and I can't seem to get it to work. Could somebody please point out what exactly I'm doing that's leading to the image not displaying?

Code for Map class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Map extends JPanel
{   
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

public Map()
{
}

public JPanel createContentPane()
{
    //Creating a base JPanel to place everything on
    JPanel rootGUI = new JPanel();
    //Setting the Layout Manager to null to place everything manually
    rootGUI.setLayout(null);
    rootGUI.setOpaque(true);
    return rootGUI;
}

private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test for image");
    //Create and set up the content pane
    Map demo = new Map();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    Hospital hDemo = new Hospital();
    frame.add(hDemo);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] Args)
{
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread
    //Creating and showing this applications GUI
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And Code for the hospital class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Hospital extends JPanel
{
static final long serialVersionUID = 2;
public static BufferedImage hospitalImage;

public Hospital()
{
    super();
    try
    {
        hospitalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\hospital.jpg"));
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        //Not handled
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(hospitalImage, 50, 50, this);
    repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions thrown? EDIT: Ok, handle that exception in your catch block (just type: `ex.printStackTrace();`) and tell me what you got.

Comment: Image isn't Null, The file is in the source folder. I added in the exception handler and nothings Come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the size of your Hospital Panel.

update to:

```
public Hospital()
{
    super();
    setSize( /* size */ );
    try
    {
        hospitalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\hospital.jpg"));
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        //Not handled
    }
}
```

or use a different layoutManager in your JFrame/ContentPane like Borderlayout

in that case you could add the Hospital to your Frame as

```
frame.add(hDemo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[visual guide to layoutmanagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Absolutely incorrect! `JPanel` will strech if you resize a JFrame. If you really want to determine size for JPanel, proper way would be to override `getPrefferedSize` method and return `Dimension` that matches `Dimension` of an image.

Comment: nope, that will only happen if you set your layoutmanager different than 'null', however in the code above the layoutmanager is set to 'null' (and depends from manager to manager)

Comment: Again incorrect. I just tested his code. Problem is of course in path he's passing. Null layout manager has nothing to do with this (until you start adding swing components on `JPanel`). Altough, I agree he should strictly avoid null layout.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in path you are passing here: `hospitalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\hospital.jpg"));`

Easy solution would be to load your image as a stream:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("hospital.jpg");
hospitalImage = ImageIO.read(stream);
stream.close();
```